# How to step over (skip debugging) concrete assembly in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

In my solution I have sources of Message Transport assembly. When debugging I would like to skip stepping into hairy sources of this assembly, but still I need to step into handler methods, which it calls. Is it possible to mark somehow that assembly so debugger will skip stepping into it's internal stuff?

It is not appropriate for me to change sources of that assembly, setting special attribute `[DebuggerStepThrough]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the Modules window and ensure that symbols for this assembly are not loaded, the debugger won't step into it. It's possible that you have Visual Studio cache the symbols and every time you debug, the symbols are loaded from the cache automatically. Go to Options -> Debugging -> Symbols and make sure no cached symbols are loaded, then debug your solution without loading this particular module's symbols and you should be good to go.